# JSON to Protobuf in Python

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

Hey I know there is a solution for this in Java, I'm curious to know if anyone knows of a Python 3 solution for converting a JSON object or file into protobuf format.  I would accept either or as converting to an object is trivial.  Searching the stackoverflow site, I only found examples of protobuf->json, but not the other way around.  There is one extremely old repo that may do this but it is in Python 2 and our pipeline is Python 3.  Any help is as always, appreciated.

Comment: protobufs have a schema, so you would de-serialize your JSON and then serialize to protobuf using a schema. what have you tried so far?

Comment: That sounds about right.  Basically there is this file format that previously used JSON, and we simply want to serialize it to valid protobuf, so that we can test the deserialization of the protobuf back to a JSON which can be passed into the API.  So far I have not really even understood what is correct to try.  `google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict` seems like it may be a viable solution, but am having trouble interpreting if this message format is the format we are most likely to receive for protobuf input if it is via a RESTful API.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The library you're looking for is [`google.protobuf.json_format`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html). You can install it with the directions in the `README` [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/python). The library is compatible with Python >= 2.7.

Example usage:

Given a protobuf message like this:

```protobuf
message Thing {
    string first = 1;
    bool second = 2;
    int32 third = 3;
}
```

You can go from Python `dict` or JSON string to protobuf like:

```
import json

from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse, ParseDict

d = {
    "first": "a string",
    "second": True,
    "third": 123456789
}

message = ParseDict(d, Thing())
# or
message = Parse(json.dumps(d), Thing())    

print(message.first)  # "a string"
print(message.second) # True
print(message.third)  # 123456789
```

or from protobuf to Python `dict` or JSON string:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict, MessageToJson

message_as_dict = MessageToDict(message)
message_as_dict['first']  # == 'a string'
message_as_dict['second'] # == True
message_as_dict['third']  # == 123456789
# or
message_as_json_str = MessageToJson(message)
```

[The documentation for the `json_format` module is here](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html).

Comment: if you see my comment above I do suggest `google.protobuf.json_format`. why would you use `Parse` instead of `ParseDict` and which is more practical for a protobuf being piped to an API?  basically trying to get a protobuf from an external source like FHIR, then pipe to a RESTful API in python

Comment: I just used `Parse` since I consume raw JSON strings more than `dict`s. Are you trying to go the other way? I.e. from message to JSON? In that case you can use `MessageToJson` or `MessageToDict`. Not sure if I'm understanding your question.

Comment: I am trying to parse a message to JSON but I need a test protobuf stream with relevant data for us to parse so basically, JSON to message piped out of python, then piped through the API, then parsed back into JSON because we will be receiving either JSONs or Protobufs

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler way by using xia-easy-proto module. No need to pre-define anything.

```
pip install xia-easy-proto
```

And then

```
from xia_easy_proto import EasyProto


if __name__ == '__main__':
    songs = {"composer": {'given_name': 'Johann', 'family_name': 'Pachelbel'},
             "title": 'Canon in D',
             "year": [1680, 1681]}
    song_class, song_payload = EasyProto.serialize(songs)
    print(song_class)  # It is the message class
    print(song_payload)  # It is the serialized message
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Looking for a long time. Could you just open source it so anyone can help improve it. It is really useful. thanks

Comment: and how is the performance? will the serialize cost too much for each record than protobuf with already generated class?

Comment: How do you think of MakeSimpleProtoClass() in google/protobuf/proto_builder.py; see google/protobuf/internal/proto_builder_test.py?

Comment: All documentation could be found in the related pip help pages. There is no performance issue if you could reuse the message class.  I will think about open sourcing it.