# Could we directly turn json or dict to protobuf serialized message without .proto in Python?

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose we have a service received different schema and insert corresponding records to bigQuery with protobuf.

But we have no way to know all schemas in advance and prepare all .proto files.

Is there any way we can directly convert json to seralized proto message without .proto and the compiled python class?
Or can we do it in runtime? like gen .proto and compile it and use the python class?

thanks

Comment: I find xia-easy-proto this lib exactly do the things I want.
But it is not open sourced and seems not much people used, wondering if there is any other better lib or method. thanks

Comment: Hi @Liu Charles, can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Hi, So you know there is legacy streaming API and storage write API for BigQuery.  Legacy Streaming API is easy to use, I only need pass json. But for storage write API we need use protobuf which need pre-defined .proto files and compiled it to python class, then create those class and call write API right.

but suppose we have a new table and we get the schema in runtime, but how do we generate .proto in runtime and compiled to python class and use it?



you can see xia-easy-proto can get serialize protobuf message without any definition.

Comment: yeah, so my question is , can we just get the protobuf class and serialized message by json data. You can see the code examples at the end of https://pypi.org/project/xia-easy-proto/, thanks

Comment: Hi @Liu Charles, For your requirement, you can try using [google.protobuf.json_format](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html) that can be used to convert protobuf to Python dict or json and Python dict or json to protobuf. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thanks. but seems json_format function still needs the class right?, like the Thing() class in this answer, which is a protocol buffer message to merge into.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345426/json-to-protobuf-in-python/73939746#comment131699527_73939746

Comment: Hi @Liu Charles, it seems this feature is not supported. If you want this feature to be included, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Hi, do you think MakeSimpleProtoClass() in https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/python/google/protobuf/proto_builder.py can help? see google/protobuf/internal/proto_builder_test.py for some example usage.